# Private slash commands

Tags: javascript, discord.js

How can I make this command have permissions that nobody but me can use and see. Like the images [img 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XSSGi.png) [img 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rH768.png)

```
const Discord = require("discord.js");

module.exports = {
  name: "ping",
  description: "nada",
  type: Discord.ApplicationCommandType.ChatInput,
  run: async (client, interaction) => {
    interaction.reply({ content: `Pong ${Math.round(client.ws.ping)}` })
  }
}
```

I've tried this:

```
const Discord = require("discord.js");

module.exports = {
  name: "ping",
  description: "nada",
  type: Discord.ApplicationCommandType.ChatInput,
  default_member_permissions: 0,
  run: async (client, interaction) => {
    interaction.reply({ content: `Pong ${Math.round(client.ws.ping)}` })
  }
}
```

`default_member_permissions: 0`, it's permission for administrators, but how do I make sure they don't even see it?

Comment: Server settings -> Integrations -> Your bot -> Change permissions

Comment: But there's a way to do this globally?

Comment: I don't use the default member permissions and others but I understood that those permissions get applied only when the bot joins a guild, basically if it is already on the guild it has to rejoin for the permissions to get applied (this might be wrong as I don't use them and idk anything about them)

Comment: Also, have you tried to deploy again the commands after you added `default_member_permissions: 0`?

Comment: The client update permissions when i restart.